# Let $G$ be a group, Then $x^{a} = e \iff o(x) | a$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group, Then $x^{a} = e \iff o(x) | a$

This should be a very trivial statement, but I'm having trouble with it.
Here $e$ is the identity an $o(x)$ is the order of element $x$.

$(\Rightarrow)$

If $ x^{a} = e$, then, as $x^{o(x)}=e$, $x^{a} = x^{o(x)}$. 
Suppose w.l.g. $o(x)>a$. Then there are $r,s$ unique integers such that
$o(x) = a.s+r$ So $x^{a} = x^{a.s+r} = (x^{a})^{s}.x^{r}$, then $s=1,r=0$, which means $o(x) = a$. In particular $o(x)|a$.

$(\Leftarrow)$

Suppose $o(x)|a$. Then $a=p.o(x)$, for some integer $p$. Then $x^{a} = x^{p.o(x)} = x^{o(x).p} = \{x^{o(x)}\}^p = e^{p} = e$

I can feel my proof is weird. There is probably something wrong in it.
Can someone please verify it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part: by definition $o(x)$ is the *smallest* nonzero natural number such that $x^{o(x)} = e$, so $x^a = e$ implies that $o(x) \leq a$. Now there are unique natural numbers $q,r$ such that $a = qo(x) + r$ *with* $0 \leq r < o(x)$. (This last part is very important!) Hence $e = x^a = (x^{o(x)})^{q}x^r = x^r$, but $r < o(x)$ contradicts the definition of $o(x)$ unless $r = 0$.

The second part is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part you have supposed $o(x)>a$, and at the end you say $o(x)=a$. Then $s\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s\neq 1$.

The other part is correct!